# Date Time split in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to split a date time which I get from a software in the below format to separate variables (year,month,day,hour, min,sec)

```
19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000
```

Note : There is two spaces between the date and time. The whole date and time is stored in a single string variable. 
Please help me in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "split"? do you want to make python datetime out of that?

Comment: I have a feeling you want to later parse and extract values, instead of splitting, I would suggest instead using [`strptime()` from `datetime` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Below solution should work for you:

```
import datetime

string = "19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000"
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%d %b %Y  %H:%M:%S.%f")

print date
```

Output would be:

```
2015-11-19 18:45:00
```

And you can access the desired values with:

```
>>> date.year
2015
>>> date.month
11
>>> date.day
19
>>> date.hour
18
>>> date.minute
45
>>> date.second
0
```

You can check [datetime's package documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) under [section 8.1.7 for `srtptime` function's usage](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative to wim's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33811125/189134), if you don't want to install a package, you can do it like so:

```
import datetime

s = "19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y  %H:%M:%S.%f")

print d.year
print d.month
print d.day
print d.hour
print d.minute
print d.second
```

This outputs:

```
2015
11
19
18
45
0
```

---

This utilizes [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to parse the string.

Comment: Might just be me but it was already installed.

Answer (score 3):

First `pip install python-dateutil` then do:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> dt = parse('19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000')
>>> dt.year
2015
>>> dt.month
11
>>> dt.day
19
>>> dt.hour
18
>>> dt.minute
45
>>> dt.second
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.strptime(your_string, format)`

To contsruct the `format` string, consult the documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

From there, you can easily [get the year, month, etc.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) (also in the documentation)

Answer (score 0):

```
df2['invoice_date']=pd.to_datetime(df2.invoice_date, format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')


df2.insert(loc=5, column='month', value=df2.invoice_date.dt.month)
# +1 to make Monday=1.....until Sunday=7
    df2.insert(loc=6, column='day', value=(df2.invoice_date.dt.dayofweek)+1)
    df2.insert(loc=7, column='hour', value=df2.invoice_date.dt.hour)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your qst :19 Nov 2015  18:45:00.000

Solution:

•) 1st store as a string in one variable
date_time=19 Nov 2015 18:45:00.000

#then use split function with a separator " " (blankspace)
#assign that result in new variable

date_time_split=date_time.split(" ")

It split up into =»like this  
date_time_split=["19","Nov","2015","18:45:00.000"]

Then for separating time just store time in one variable using list index. I hope u know about list index or array index .

Do...

new_time=date_time_split[3]

Now execute splitting

time_final=new_time.split(":") # using separator :
Now it will be

["18","45","00.000"]

Now by way of accessing index position you can print it separately  ✴️. Its a very easy way to Spilt date_time

I Hope you understood it clearly.!
Checkout !

Comment: Please format your code correctly, so that it's more readable for others.