# How to split Python datetime object to date and time numbers?

Tags: python, datetime

I would like to store a Python datetime object as date number and time number in a database.  How do you split the datetime object into date and time numbers ?

```
Today = datetime.today()
TodayNumber = Today.timestamp() #-- this returns a FLOAT

Day = Today.date()  #- date object
Time = Today.time()  #- time object

DayNumber = Day.whatfuntion() #- internal represtation for date in INTEGER
TimeNumber = Time.whatfundtion() #- internal representation for time in INTEGER
```

Update - the  slution for date is to convert to the gregorial oridnal

```
DayNumber = Day.toordinal() #- internal represtation for date in INTEGER
```

Comment: In what format do you want the output?, please give an example.

Comment: Please check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810980/date-time-split-in-python/33811625 Possible duplicate

Comment: Format it once for just the date, and once for just the time parts?

Comment: In addition to what @KondasamyJayaraman said, if you need just one of the values you can do `datetime.` and press tab, that should give you a list to pick from like `day`, `hour`, `microseconds` etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Date Time split in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810980/date-time-split-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "date number" and "time number". But the following may solve your issue:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> year, month, day, hour, minute, second, *_ = datetime.now().timetuple()
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple for documentation.

Comment: I ahve the date and time in a datetime object and would like to store date and time as two INTEGER in a database, the datetime,timestamp() equivalent for date and time.

Comment: This is what u need, a timetuple splits DateTime object to several integers

Comment: I found the answer for date - cnvert it to Gregorian ordinal