# Splitting data in a csv cell into 2 cells

Tags: python

I have a data set that has a column that has combined the date and time of the events i'm looking at in a csv file and I want to split them into separate columns.

The format of the column values is:
2016-12-31T21:57:40.910Z

so DateTTimeOZ

is there any way i can do this in python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date Time split in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33810980/date-time-split-in-python)

Comment: Yes it's possible - it would help people give relevant answers if you added details to your question - for example, if you read your dataset using pandas, there's a different optimum way of doing it, vs. if you use some other library, vs. using vanilla python. The more complete your question (e.g. including a [mre]), the better answers you'll get. [Ask]. Please also take the [tour] and read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) that can help you ask questions better.

Answer (score 1):

If you are indeed using pandas, you can split them into multiple columns like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': ['2016-12-31T21:57:40.910Z', '2020-1-31T12:52:10.910Z']})
```

**Input df**

```
    datetime
0   2016-12-31T21:57:40.910Z
1   2020-1-31T12:52:10.910Z
```

**Convert to datetime**

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

**Split to different columns**

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['datetime'].dt.time
df['time_string'] = df['datetime'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

**Output**

```
datetime                             date            time      time_string
2016-12-31 21:57:40.910000+00:00    2016-12-31  21:57:40.910000 21:57:40
2020-01-31 12:52:10.910000+00:00    2020-01-31  12:52:10.910000 12:52:10
```

If you are not using pandas, then let us know more information so we can help further

Comment: yes that helps! I am using Pandas but I am trying to do that to an entire column

Comment: I just updated the sample I/O to show it works on an entire column. You can accept the answer if it works for you otherwise let us know where else you get stuck

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard library, you can do something like this:

```py
import csv
import datetime as dt

import io
content = """DATETIME;VALUE
2016-12-31T21:57:40.910Z;EEEEEEE
2018-01-29T21:57:40.910Z;FFFFFFF"""

# Replace `io.StringIO(content)` with `open('input/file/path', 'r')`
# Replace `io.StringIO()` with `open('output/file/path', 'w', newline='')`
with io.StringIO(content) as f_in, io.StringIO() as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=';')
    writer = csv.writer(f_out, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')

    # Create the new file header, spliting "DATETIME" into "DATE" and "TIME"
    # I don't know what is your datetime column name, but replace it as you wish
    header = next(reader)
    new_header = []
    for column_name in header:
        if column_name == 'DATETIME':
            new_header.append('DATE')
            new_header.append('TIME')
        else:
            new_header.append(column_name)

    writer.writerow(new_header)
    
    # Iterate over each row
    for row in reader:
        new_row = []
        for name, value in zip(header, row):
            if name == 'DATETIME':
                # Parse the datetime string ("2016-12-31T21:57:40.910Z") as a datetime object
                dto = dt.datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
                # Split the datetime object into two strings: date and time
                new_row.append(dto.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
                new_row.append(dto.strftime("%H:%M:%S.%f"))

            else:
                new_row.append(value)

        writer.writerow(new_row)

    print(f_out.getvalue())
    # Output:
    # DATE;TIME;VALUE
    # 2016-12-31;21:57:40.910000;EEEEEEE
    # 2018-01-29;21:57:40.910000;FFFFFFF
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity -- will this work faster than pandas? Or is there a distinct advantage of using this over pandas?

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal The only advantage of this is if you're not using Pandas and don't want to download a whole library just for this simple task that can be done using the standard library.